# Dimensionality problem in special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, linear-algebra, spacetime-dimensions

Suppose $A$ is a null $4$-vector in Minkowski space-time, $M$. Then the vector space spanned by $A$: $\operatorname{span}(A)$ is unidimensional. The orthogonal complement of this vector space $\operatorname{span}_\perp(A)$ is in fact the same vector space since the only $4$-vector orthogonal to a null vector is one that is also null and parallel to the first one.
So we have
$$\operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{span}(A))+\operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{span}_\perp(A))=2.$$

From linear algebra this sum should be equal to $\operatorname{dim}(M)=4$. ([orthogonal complements](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1766613/))

I came up with this argument and I cannot find its flaw, although I know it is wrong. If anyone could help me find the mistake I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: To show that theorem you assume a positive definite inner product. That’s not the case in special relativity.

Answer (score -3):

https://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol3-trans/385

DOC. 21    MOLECULAR MOTION IN SOLIDS   Page 371

In full: Elementary Observations on Thermal Molecular Motion in Solids

Elementare Betrachtungen über die thermische Molekularbewegung in festen Körper

1911 Annalen der Physic 35: 679-694

Section §3:  Dimensional Argument Concerning Lindemann's Formula and My Formula for the Determination of the Proper Frequency

As we all know, dimensional arguments allow us chiefly to find general functional relations between physical quantities if all physical quantities occurring in the relation in question are known. For example, if we know that the oscillation period T of a mathematical pendulum can only depend on the length of the pendulum l, on the acceleration of free fall g, on the mass of the pendulum m, and on no other quantity, then a simple dimensional argument will lead us to the conclusion that the relation must be given by the equation T = C × sqrt( 1 / g )  where C is a dimensionless number. But as we know, there is still something more that can be inferred from the dimensional argument, even though not in a completely rigorous way. Namely, dimensional numerical factors (as the factor C in this instance), the magnitude of which can only be deduced by means of a more or less detailed mathematical theory, are generally on the order of magnitude one. To be sure, this cannot be strictly required, because why should it not be possible for a numerical factor ( 12π )³ to appear in a mathematical-physical analysis? But such cases are unquestionably rare. Suppose, therefore, that we had measured the oscillation period T and the pendulum length l of an individual mathematical pendulum and that the above formula had yielded us 10¹° as the value of the constant C; in that case we would already look upon our formula with justified suspicion. Conversely, our trust would grow if we found from our experimental data that C is, say, 6.3; our basic assumption that the relation sought contains only the quantities T, l, and g, but no other quantities, would gain in probability in our eyes.

Comment: Why don't the moderators delete this?